# Heroku missing required flag when restoring database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I've seen a couple of SO posts, and despite googleing and the `heroku --help`, I keep getting the same error

I've been working off of this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

```
$ heroku pg:backups:restore 'secure-file-location-url' DATABASE_URL --app heroku-app-name --confirm heroku-app-name
Starting restore of secure-file-location-url to postgresql-flat-47715... done

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup will continue restoring.
Use heroku pg:backups to check progress.
Stop a running restore with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Restoring... !
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸    
 ▸    waiting for restore to complete
 ▸    pg_restore finished with errors
 ▸    waiting for download to complete
 ▸    download finished with errors
 ▸    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
 ▸    
 ▸    Run heroku pg:backups:info r018 for more details.
$ heroku pg:backups:info r018
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

My `secure-file-location-url` is a public Google Drive link, which I can access in an incognito browser window.

Comment: (a) Please add `--app heroku-app-name` to your `pg:backups:info` command and see what comes back. (b) Is `'secure-file-location-url'` publicly accessible? If not, what restrictions are in place to protect it?

Comment: `pg:backups:info 
No backups. Capture one with heroku pg:backups:capture
`

Which makes sense, because I'm trying to populate an db with a `pg_dump` file

The file is being read from a public google drive link - there's nothing important in there, just 13k personal records

Comment: Can you access the file from an incognito browser window?

Comment: Yes, I can access it.

Comment: And it's a direct link to the file? It doesn't load in some kind of viewer or Google Drive "click to download" page?

Comment: Yeah, it does... Interesting

Comment: It does... what? Load in a viewer or a "click to download" page? You'll need to provide a direct link to the file. I think the documentation recommends using Amazon S3 for this.

Comment: I shows a viewer/click to download page. I also just tried using a direct download link from an S3 bucket and got the same error.

Comment: I just tried again and now I have the 'missing magic string' error, which is a formatting problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. I'll add an answer now that we know what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your database dump is being hosted on Google Drive and the link you're providing goes to a viewer with a "download file" button.

Instead, you must provide a direct link to the file. The documentation recommends using Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, how I solved it was by adding run to the Heroku CLI command. Formatted like so:
`heroku pg:backups:restore '<signed url>' DATABASE_URL -a <your-application-name>`
Literally, put DATABASE_URL in there and it will read it from your environment variables. If you try putting in the postgress address it will fail. Also, the application needs to be the last thing added to this command, order matters here.